# Find the number of real solutions of $x^2+e^x=\sin x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of real solutions of:
$e^x+x^2= \sin x$

Graphically, I am unable to derive any solutions. Also, how could I estimate the real solutions?

Comment: Which set does $x$ belong to ?

Comment: @PandaBear OP is aksing for "real solutions".

Comment: I am more interested in the number of solutions than the exact solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no solutions. Intuitively, [this graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5Ex+%2B+x%5E2%2C+sin%28x%29) shows you why there are no solutions.

For the analytic proof there are no solutions, Prove that for $x\notin[-2,0]$, the function $e^x+x^2$ is larger than $1$, while on $[-2,0]$, it is larger than $0$.

More hints: Showing that $e^x+x^2 > 0$ should be trivial. The fact that $e^x + x^2>x^2$ should prove that $e^x+x^2>1$ for $x<-2$, and a similar expression will take care of $x>0$.

Comment: Why do you plot $e^2+x^2$ and not $e^x+x^2$?

Comment: @gammatester I fixed it, it was my sloppy writing.

Comment: How can I show this rigorously?

Comment: @AdityaParson I added one more hint.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple.

Clearly $x^2+e^x>1$ when $x>0$ so there are no positive solutions

Also, clearly that for $x<-1$, $x^2+e^x>1$ so there is no solution below -1.

For $-1\leq x<0$ you have $\sin x<0$ but $x^2+e^x>0$ you still get no solution.

This leaves you with only $x=0$. However, $0^2+e^0=1$ while $\sin 0=0$ so it isn't a solution either.

Thus there are no real solutions.

If you wanted complex solutions instead, there are two answers: $x\approx0.07315\pm0.80702i$